# recursive jquery function and check afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I deploy two functions on my gallery page. One to display -one by one- the list items with images, and two to check and remove those items where the images (external) won't load.

The first one works excellent, but the second does not. Can't figure out why. Does anyone knows this one?

```
var r = 0,
    selector = "ul.display li:hidden:first";

function fadeIn($item) {
    $item.fadeIn(200, function() {
        var n = $(selector);
        if (n.length > 0) {
            fadeIn($(selector));
        } else {
            // add a div
            $(".navigate").show("fast");
            $("#downunder").show("slow");
        }
    })
}


fadeIn($(selector));
function myFunc() {
    $("ul.display li img").each(function(index) {
        if ((!this.width || !this.height)) {
            pos3 = $(this).attr("id");
            reportrefcam();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }

        $(this).error(function() {
            pos3 = $(this).attr("id");
            reportrefcam();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
};

myFunc();
```

Comment: Why are you putting the function in a variable? `function myFunc(){` would do.

Comment: Code is a **lot** easier to read and debug when it's properly indented. Your `myFunc` code indentation is all over the place.

Comment: TJ : I have made to markup a bit more readible

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just fixed the indentation

Comment: @mark: The problem wasn't the markup, it was the indentation. TimWolla had to finally fix it for you. Speaking quite seriously, proper, consistent indentation (whatever style you want to use is fine) ***will*** help you avoid creating bugs, and make it easier to find when you do.

Comment: I mean the indention. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Where does it fail? At what point in the code is that? Have you tried putting alerts in your code to see how far it gets and display the variables it is checking? Seeing your code in action might help, can you provide a link?

Comment: I don't understand why don't you use the onload event to trace which images don't load, and therefor check with a timeout those whom didn't and remove those ones. Have you check that the second selector gives any result?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. You are checking to see if image has a width and height...

this.height won't work.

Either use: this.style.height or $(this).height();

Comment: myFunc() as a standalone used to work, now that I use fadeIn it is not.

Comment: See my other comment on your question for more info.